# "Hiding" things in GIT

Tags: git, version-control

Git noob here.

I know this is against the principal of "distributed source control" but I want to "password protect" certain development branches in my GIT repository.  That is, I don't want that branch to be available via `git branch -r`, except to a certain group of developers who need access to that branch, via some sort of password.

Possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a separate repository cloned from the public one with its own branches.

This repository could be in the filesystem with the right ACLs or group permissions, or it could be a separate server requiring proper login credentials, etc. Then developers could commit, pull, merge, etc. as authorized.

Answer (score 3):

Why not make a separate git repository and allow only you and that certain group of developers access (this can be accomplished using [gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way))?

And if you are not already using gitosis, I suggest you do so.

Comment: Or gitolite instead of gitosis.

Comment: +1 for gitolite -- it allows exactly this type of per-branch permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. It would make things like merging near impossible since git needs to know about the branches in order to make a merge. Consider the situation where one of your trusted developers merge something from the hidden branch to your main branch. Then a non-trusted developer tries to merge his changes -> how would you resolve the conflicts?

But it's simple to get what you want: just have a separate repository and use that as a "branch" since merging from a different repository is about as easy as merging a branch in the same repository.