# How can one prevent a specific tag or branch from being fetched in a remote bare repository?

Tags: git, repository, branch, acl, fetch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Hiding” things in GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321176/hiding-things-in-git)

Is it possible to lock specific tags or branches down so they can't be fetched?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, since when you clone a repository, you get the whole history and can then have access to all tags / branches / ...

What you can do is have two repository, one private where all those restricted branches / tags are present, and a public one where you only push branches / tags that should be accessible. You cannot make them disappear however.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you keep those branches locally as opposed to remote. Whenever someone clones a repository they get the entire thing. That's the joy of distributed version control.